# javascript jquery вопрос про конкатенацию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я передаю в аргумент функции elem -  `foo(elem);`

В функции, мне нужно найти img в elem, это можно сделать так - `$(elem).find('img');`

Но у меня есть вопрос, возможно ли обойтись без find? Допустим, без переменной, это можно было бы сделать так - `$('div img').todo();` но  когда я пытаюсь сделать так - `$(elem+' img').todo();` в консоли вылетает ошибка.

Comment: а `elem` это что в вашем случае ? строка с селектором или же js||jquery обьект ?

Answer (score 1):

Без `.find()` не обойтись, но можно "синтаксически подсластить". Написать так:

```
$('img', elem);
```

См. [аргумент `context`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)